# Docker hub with two images

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, angular-cli, dockerhub

I wrote a program with java spring boot and angular cli and wrote the docker file for both and it works with docker compose so that in docker compose the angular links to spring boot.
When I want to upload to docker hub I uploaded the two images but the docker compose can't be uploaded.
How do I links between two containers?

Thanks

Edit:
Here's link to my docker compose in github

https://www.github.com/GillieDudikman/item-springboot-angular/tree/master/docker-compose.yml

Comment: Would you mind sharing your compose?

Comment: Give a link to github/gitlab/etc.. with the docker-compode and README.md

Answer (score 0):

You do not upload your docker compose file to docker hub. Docker hub is an image repository not a code repository. Push your code to GitHub or bitbucket instead
When someone wants to use your images they can pull them from docker hub and use them like any other image. You can add to the description in docker hub how to use the images and even a link to your project if you want.